# Put a function that counts object in an array into another function

Tags: javascript, html

I have made this function that counts an object in an array but I want to put it in another function, it has to work in another function I've made.
I want it to be vert vanilla java because I am new to programming

```js
var markers = [
  {
    type:"Chocolate",
    name:"KitKat",
    group:"candy",
    icon:"candy",
    coords:[5246,8980],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Orange",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Banana",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Rice",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Meat",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Beam",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Water",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Coffe",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
];

function counter(){
var count = {}

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  count[markers[i].type] = count[markers[i].type] + 1 || 1;
}
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(count);
}
counter();
```

this one here

```js
function make(){
var pg = '<table>'
    for(i = 0;i < markers.length; i++){
       pg += '<td>' + ??? + '</td>'; // I would like to put it here
       og += '<td>' + markers[i].name + '</td>';
        og += '</tr>';
    }
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = pg;
}
```

I hope somenone can help me, also if we have to change the functions so they can work togehther

Answer (score 1):

You can return the object from that previous function instead of directly rendering it to the DOM.

```js
function counter() {
  var count = {}

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    count[markers[i].type] = count[markers[i].type] + 1 || 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Replace the `???` with `JSON.stringify(counter())`.